# Is GWT supported on the PlayBook?

Tags: javascript, gwt, blackberry-playbook

We have a web application built with GWT 2.4 that does not seem to work on the Playbook. Does the Blackberry Playbook tablet support GWT at all?

Comment: It's not a matter of supporting GWT, but rather Blackberry OS 7 not supporting proper Javascript.

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured...

Answer (score 1):

Check out these links:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Tablet-OS-SDK-for-Adobe-AIR/Accessing-blackberry-javascript-APIs-from-GWT/td-p/1027307

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/bd-p/browser_dev

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/GWT-and-OS7-don-t-play-well-together/td-p/1448611

From the latter:

> If you ever wonder why your GWT app doesn't start on a blackberry OS7,
>   you might be experiencing the same problem I had a week ago. I spend a
>   couple of hours investigating and basically, if you try to perform a
>   Integer.parseInt, it fails miserably. Nothing in the logs, nothing in
>   the console, etc. Debugging the JS gwt code I found that it's checking
>   on the min/max value of an int. And guess what? OS7 browser doesn't
>   support them...